# Epicor asking for password after making a table change

Tags: database, database-design, epicorerp

Epicor - what a beastly creature!
Epicor asking for password after making a table change, any idea why?!?!
We removed the relationship from the (part table) and set up a criteria, instead. Now it is asking for a password, which should not be happening.
the login happens when I try to run the report. I am trying to figure out what I did to aggravate Epicor. The table was already there. I removed the relationship (part table) and added a criteria, instead, otherwise, that is exactly what I would have done. The only reason that I did not add a table to a report data definition, like I originally wanted to is because the parts table could only be added once. Which is why I removed the relationship and added a criteria, instead.

Comment: the login happens when I try to run the report. I am trying to figure out what I did to aggravate Epicor. The table was already there. I removed the relationship (part table) and added a criteria, instead, otherwise, that is exactly what I would have done. The only reason that I did not add a table to a report data definition, like I originally wanted to is because the parts table could only be added once. Which is why I removed the relationship and added a criteria, instead.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like the problem is related to the xml generated by Epicor for a non-BAQ based report data definition.  Crystal and SSRS reports ask login information when either there is more than one datasource is referenced in the report, or there is improper relationships defined.

**Note:**
If you are not a report developer and you have modified this in an attempt to change the end data, I recommend you contact the report developer responsible for maintaining these before proceeding.  Otherwise, read on.

Based on my experience, I would say if you are confident in the new relationship structure you have in the report data definition, the solution to this problem is likely within the report itself.  Generate an xml file by running a test report, then open the .rpt (or .rdl) associated with this report and set the datasource to the new xml file.  This should update the new xml schema used as the datasource.  Even if none of the fields were changed in the data definition, the datasource schema definition that is stored in these files define exactly the data formatting that the report expects to receive when it is opened by Epicor.

If that doesn't solve the problem and you are using Crystal, the xml relationships may be defined in a way that will effect the way the data is displayed, which can be adjusted by using database expert->links tab in crystal.  You should reconnect all of the links to match the report data definition within Epicor.

If none of that works, open up and view the xml file.
It is not unheard of for report data definitions in Epicor to break behind the scenes when altering relationships, and the xml file generated by the test report may not be a fully-qualified xml file.  I have seen many xml files that do not have elements closed, etc. that will cause various problems when attempting to run the report.  In this case, my recommendation is to create a completely new report data definition (do not copy), and re-enter all of the parameters that existed in the former definition.  Repeat the refreshing of the report datasource as described above and this problem should be fixed.